# bundle.containskey("xx") return true yet systems throws npe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I am trying to pass data between activity and its fragment using bundles. Following is the code I am using:

Activity:

```
            Fragment newmaf = new Fragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("xx",xx);
            args.putString("yy",yy);
            newmaf.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.view_pager,newmaf);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();
```

Fragment:

```
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        Log.d(tag,"bundle contents: "+bundle.toString() +" has xx: "+bundle.containsKey("xx"));
        storeName = bundle.getString("xx");
        dateOfPurchase = bundle.getString("yy");
```

The thing is, while bundle.tostring() and bundle.containsKey("xx") shows me my data and returns TRUE respectively, I still get the following error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.toString()' on a null object reference
```

Output of the Log statement:

```
2020-01-28 22:43:05.988 23850-23850/com.example.sf_v000 D/MAF: bundle contents: Bundle[{xx=123, yy=123}] has xx: true
```

I am unable to solve this issue. Can anyone help here?

Thanks!

Comment: `bundle.getString()` should not throw a NullPointerException, even if the key "xx" wasn't present. It would just _return_ null. Can you post the actual exception message that you get, so we can look at the stacktrace?

Comment: I had misunderstood the error. Have updated my question and have added the error message as well. Help appreciated.

Comment: It appears the "bundle" itself is `null`. Is the Fragment code still valid? The Logcat message (starting with "bundle contents") doesn't match the message in the source code (starting with "is empty") you posted earlier.

Comment: I do not understand by "fragment code still valid?". You are correct about the logcat message, was testing some things out so got the logcat message from a different version of my code than the one I posted here... have updated my question

Comment: The message clearly states the error occurs when calling `toString()` on a `Bundle` variable that is `null`, but since `Log.d` shows output from its `bundle.toString()` call, the error is not thrown from the code you think it is. Check the error message, behind the message text, there should be the exact location (filename and line number) where the exception occurred. It is either from a different place in the code, or `getArguments()` only sometimes returns null.

Answer (score 0):

### What likely happens

The problem is that sometimes your `bundle` variable is `null`, and sometimes it isn't.

### What you experienced

On an occasion where `bundle` was `null`, the `storeName = bundle.getString("xx");` line threw a NPE when attempting to call `getString("xx")` on the `null` reference in `bundle`.

You probably misunderstood that exception, thinking that `getString()` itself had the problem. You then added the `Log.d` line, which includes a call to `bundle.toString()`. This causes the error to now appear in `bundle.toString()` already since this new code line is above the call to `bundle.getString("xx")`.

Probably, the method is called twice. During the first pass, `getArguments()` returns a `Bundle` object. Both the calls to `bundle.toString()` and `bundle.getString("xx")` work as intended, causing the `Log.d` print out to show that the key `"xx"` is indeed in the bundle. On the second pass, `getArguments()` returns `null`, causing a NPE to occur when calling `bundle.toString()` for the argument of `Log.d`.

That is: whether or not any particular key is in the bundle, is unrelated to the NullPointerException you are experiencing. Try to find out when and why `getArguments()` returns `null`.

### How to fix

I'd recommend to replace the current `Log.d` line with `Log.d(tag, "bundle is " + bundle);`. This will allow you to verify that the `bundle` variable is `null`. Your Logcat output will most likely look like this:

```
D/MAF: bundle is android.os.Bundle@f65ad1a3
D/MAF: bundle is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

This would prove that the code is passed once with a bundle object (first line) and then again without a bundle object (second line) which will cause the NPE to occur when the first method is called on the null reference (third line).

You can then proceed to add a breakpoint to the line `storeName = bundle.getString("xx");`. Run the app in debug mode, and each time, take a look at the stack trace. This will help you to understand where you come from when `getArguments()` returns the `Bundle` as expected and when it doesn't.